# Swagger restful documentation

Tags: java, rest, swagger

I am using Swagger to generate Restful services' documentation. However, I want to show in the documentation that the response class may be one of a children classes. For example: Rule Class is the super class, C1 and C2 are sub-classes of Rule.

I have a restful service that returns C1 instance or C2 instance based on the input. I wrote:

```
@GET
@Path("/getRule/{id}/{ruleType}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@ApiOperation(value = "returns Rule based on id and type .", notes = "", response = Rule.class)
public Rule getRule(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @PathParam("ruleType") RuleType ruleType) {

    Rule result = getRuleBasedOnIdType(id, ruleType);
    return result;
}
```

What I need is to show on Swagger documentation that this service may return a model of Class C1 or a Model of Class C2. I know that I can write 2 services for the two response classes (C1 or C2) but I prefer to have one service for the two responses.

I want to provide one api instead of having many. The input (for example: id and type) should determine the output type and the consumer should knows that a response of Type X will be returned based on input value for type parameters 'X'

Anyone has suggestions?

Comment: From an API consumer's perspective, aren't they going to consume a `Rule` instance either way? IMHO, you documentation should reflect the external usage (as opposed to your internal implementation)

Comment: The consumer should know the model of the response based on the parameters sent to the API (know the expected response class type). Yes it is a `Rule` instance but at the same time it will be `C1` instance which have additional properties and different from `C2` properties.

Comment: I disagree, the consumer should not have to know the underlying implementation - that's why you are exposing the endpoint as such (i.e. if you are returning a `List`, you don't *need* to know if you get an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`) - you handle the `List` and move on.  If the consumer **needs** to know the underlying rule implementation, you are exposing your app's internal (in some places, this is could be considered a design flaw) - Now, if consumer is asking for rule based on `id` and `type` - don't they know already the `type` they will expect?

Comment: the consumer should know the model (type) based on Swagger documentation. As you know the documentation shows the type of response and based on that consumer knows how to receive the response. This is what i need to tell the consumer that this API may return multiple types based on the input via Swagger documentation. I actually don't expose the internal implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c#, web api, swashbuckler/swagger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902672/c-web-api-swashbuckler-swagger)

Comment: It is the same case yes, but the answer is not fair enough. I want to provide one api instead of having many. The input (for example: id and type) should determine the output type and the consumer should knows that a  response of Type X will be returned based on input value for type parameters 'X' ... any more suggestions ?